# WordPress loop odd numbered posts based on ID and then even posts based on ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I am in need to just display odd numbered WordPress POST ID and then just display even numbered POST ID.

Is there a way to modify my current code below so that I can just run two loops one just displaying posts with an odd number ID and one that displays ones with an even number ID?

```
<!-- loop posts -->
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'DESC'));

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

$postLink = get_post_meta($post->ID, "postLink", true);

$classes = array(
    'blogOverviewLoop',
    'col06',
    'darkGrey'
    );
?>

<div <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>
    <article>
        <?php get_template_part( 'pf', get_post_format() ) ?>
    </article>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: you want 2 loops? or just all the posts with odd even etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `get_posts`:

```
//Arguments
$args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'DESC');
//Get posts with arguments
$getposts = get_posts($args);

//Initialize post values
$posta = array();
$postb = array();

//Set the counter to 1
$i=1;

//Loop as long as there are posts.
foreach ($getposts AS $post) {
    //Get an individual post and add it to individual buckets.
    if($i%2 == 1) {
        $posta[] = $post;
    } else {
        $postb[] = $post;
    }
}
```

Now `posta` and `postb` contain odd and even posts, respectively. You can loop through at your leisure and post as you would like. Alternatively you can probably append data to different buckets rather than assigning them to different variable arrays. That would help you avoid a second or third loop.

See the Wordpress Codex [Template Tags/get posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) for more details.